# Magento admin grid sortable?

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, grid, customize

I would like to change a little the way how is my table will look like and behave but I can't locate the class/function which is generating tables. Can anyone please tell me where to look at?
All I wanted to achieve was make my table sortable (vertically).
So loaded jQuery.ui, added .js into layout and problem solved.
Now my module allow me to set Brands order quickly just using drag/drop mechanism.[image][image]

I can use it on any menu to change order as I want ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this [BL Custom Grid](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-grids-editor.html) extension for a few years and found it really useful. Not sure if this is exactly what you're referring to though.

Comment: Already sorted, simple jQuery script.